# Singular conics in the pencil

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I try to solve following exersize (7.24 from *3264 & All That Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry* by Eisenbud and Harris)

> Let $S \subset \mathbb P^3$ be a smooth cubic surface and $L \subset S$
> a line. Let $C_t$ be the pencil of conics on
> S cut out by the pencil of planes $H_t$ containing L. How many of the
> conics $C_t$ are singular? Use this to answer the question of how many
> other lines on S meet L.

Don't we need here some additional assumptions? It seems to me that in case of the surface $V(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3)$ and line $V(x + y, z+w)$ all the conics from the pencil seems to be singular (at the point $[1:-1:t:-t]$ on the hypersurface $(x + y + t^2z + t^2w)$), as the singular locus of $C_{t^2}$ is cut out ideal
$$
\left(z^{2}-w^{2},x^{2}-y^{2},x+y+t^{2}z+t^{2}w,xy^{2}+y^{3}+z^{3}+w^{3},t^{2}z^{2}-t^{2}w^{2},t^{2}y^{2}-w^{2}\right)
$$

Are my calculations wrong, or should we choose here for example some general surface?

Comment: I am not sure how you compute, but I suspect that you compute just the intersection of the cubic with a hyperplane. This is indeed singular, because it is equal to the union of the fixed line and a conic. So, you need to get rid of the line component.